# On extension of endofunctors to pro/ind-objects and preservation of (co)limits

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

Suppose that $\mathsf{C}$ is a cocomplete category and $F : \mathsf{C} \to \mathsf{C}$ is and endofunctor together with a natural transformation $\eta : \mathsf{C} \to 1$. Then, for any $x \in X$ one can form the diagram

$$
x \xleftarrow{\eta} Fx \xleftarrow{F \eta} F^2x \xleftarrow{F^2\eta} F^3x \leftarrow \cdots \tag{$\star$}
$$

which is an object in $\mathsf{pro-C}$. Now, given an arrow $f : x \to y$ in $\mathsf{C}$ then we have a natural transformation between the constructions in $(\star)$ via $F^kf : F^kx \to F^ky$.

Similarly we have a construction for $\mathsf{ind-C}$ when having a natural transformation $\xi : 1 \to \mathsf{C}$. If I am not mistaken, the natural transformations constitute morphisms between the pro/ind objects.

For example, in general given $X,Y : I \to \mathsf{C}$ two ind-objects with common domain, then a natural transformation $\mu : X \Rightarrow Y$ gives maps $\mu_i : X_i \to Y_i$ and so their equivalence classes in $\mathsf{colim}_J(X_i,Y_j)$ should assemble into an element of $\mathsf{lim} \ \mathsf{colim}\hom(X_i,Y_j) = \hom(X,Y)$.

In particular, for the first case, we have a functor

$$
\widetilde{F} : \mathsf{C} \to \mathsf{pro-C}.
$$

> If $F$ preserves (co)limits, does $\widetilde{F}$ preserve (co)limits? What about the case for ind-objects?

The motivation for this question comes from the baricentric subdivision functor on simplicial **sets**. Since it is a left adjoint, it preserves all colimits, and I am interested in knowing if the extension to pro-simplicial **sets** does too.

**Edit:** for the purposes of what I am trying to understand, the following more concrete question suffices.

Given $K$ a simplicial set, we can for its baricentric subdivision

$$
\mathsf{sd} K = \lim_{\Delta^n \to K} \mathsf{sd} \Delta^n
$$

where $\mathsf{sd} \Delta^n$ is the simplicial set associated with the baricentric subdivision of $\Delta^n$ as a simplicial complex.

The so called 'last vertex map' gives a natural transformation $\ell : \mathsf{sd} \to 1$, hence for any simplicial set $K$ we have a pro-simplicial set

$$
\mathsf{sd}^\bullet K := K \xleftarrow{\ell} \mathsf{sd} K \xleftarrow{\mathsf{sd}\ell} \mathsf{sd}^2 K \leftarrow \cdots
$$

and as described, a functor

$$
\mathsf{sd}^{\bullet}(-) : \mathsf{sSet} \to \mathsf{pro-sSet}.
$$

> Does $\mathsf{sd}^\bullet$ send finite colimits to finite colimits? Can changing the codomain to $\mathsf{sSet}^{\mathbb{N}^{op}}$ make a difference?

Comment: for colimits you need ind-completions... Moreover, pro/ind completion are characterised by a (2-dimensional) universal property. For ind-completion, [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404902001263) might be a bit of an overkill, but (in my opinion) it is a fundamental piece of technology for addressing some questions in this ballpark

Comment: Would you mind expanding on the ind-completions case? What about the concrete example of the subdivision functor? Do colimits go to limits here?

Comment: Well, given a category $C$ its Ind-completion is characterised by the following universal property: every functor $F: C \to D$ where $D$ admits filtered colimits has a unique extension, given by Kan extension, to a functor $\bar F : \text{Ind-}C\to D$. This is similar, in all respects, to the universal property of the presheaf category. Coming to your question: I can probably say something more for simplicial *sets* instead of complexes, but I'm not an expert. PS: ma ci conosciamo?

Comment: Are you asking about *all* (co)limits, or are you also looking for results involving only certain types of (co)limits ? For instance, the usual $C\to Pro(C)$ preserves finite limits, hence if $F$ preserves finite limits, so does $\tilde F$. More generally, $\tilde F$ can be written as an inverse limit of functors of the form $C\to C\to Pro(C)$, where the second $C\to Pro(C)$ is the usual embedding. So it will preserve any limit that $C\overset F\to C \to Pro(C)$ preserves

Comment: PPS: you might want to take a look at Theorem 2.4 of said paper

Comment: @MaximeRamzi for my purposes finite ones will do, actually, but I was curious about the general case.

Comment: @Fosco thanks once again, I will look into that paper. I'd appreciate an answer to the simplicial sets case (I meant sets instead of complexes in the first place). PS: despite my deceivingly italian username I don't think we know each other (ma hai risposto alcune delle mie domande qui in MSE, quindi ricordo il tuo nome).

Comment: However, I'm not sure $C\to Pro(C)$ preserves finite limits when $C$ is not small - in fact I'm not sure what the definition of $Pro(C)$ is, when $C$ is not small

Comment: @MaximeRamzi I see. I will update my question to the case I am interested in, then. As for the definition, maybe I am missing something, but following the nLab: a pro-object is a functor $I \to  C$ with $I$ a small cofiltering category, morphisms from $X : I \to C$ to $Y:J \to C$ are defined as $\text{colim lim} \hom(X_\bullet,Y_\bullet)$.

Comment: You're right, I was thinking of another definition.

Comment: I just saw your edit: *yes*, changing to $\mathsf{sSet}^{\mathbb N^{op}}$ makes a huge difference- the latter is a functor category, so its colimits are computed pointwise, in particular if you have a sequence of functors $\dots \to F_n\to \dots \to F_1\to F_0$, seeing it as one functor $\mathsf{sSet}\to\mathsf{sSet}^{\mathbb N^{op}}$, it preserves colimits if and only if each $F_i$ does